# Linker error when loading .obj file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm tring to load an obj file containing sphere vertices using this [obj loader](http://www.kixor.net/dev/objloader/) and I get this error when I compile:

`1>ShaderPerspective.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall objLoader::load(char *)" (?load@objLoader@@QAEHPAD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl loadObj(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadObj@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z`)

The code that fails is:

```
void loadObj(const std::string &strObjFile)
{
    objLoader *objData = new objLoader();
    objData->load("data\\sphere.obj");  
}
```

I know that this is a linker error but being a bit of a beginner with c++ and Visual Studio , if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to get this to work I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? I suspect you just need to include its project as part of your solution. Or possibly just add its .obj file to the linker options.

Comment: I tried including the header files like so:

#include "../objTester/list.h"
#include "../objTester/obj_parser.h"
#include "../objTester/objLoader.h"
#include "../objTester/string_extra.h"

which gave the error above.  I've just added the project to my solution to see if that works, but how do I include it in my current project?